# Maven: Command line to download the dependencies described in the pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I would like to know the maven command line to download the dependencies described in the pom.xml.
It is that : mvn dependency:copy-dependencies ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [dependency:go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) goal. It's meant to be used to resolve dependencies to the local repo before using the `-o` switch to go to offline mode. But the goal itself has no bearing on going offline. The name may be misleading.

> Goal that resolves all project dependencies, including plugins and reports and their dependencies.

Here's the details about the [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) in case you're interested

---

Anther option is the [dependency:resolve](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html) goal

> Goal that resolves the project dependencies from the repository.