# Java async-http-client difficulties installng

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I am trying to follow the directions for setting up this async-http-client
[Here](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). According to the readme, I can either add the dependancy to my maven project .pom file(which I don't want because I did not create a maven project), or I can use the link and download the library directly.

When I try to download the lib I get runtime errors because i'm missing the netty dependencies, which confuses me because I would expect that everything would be inclusive if they are offering the lib stand alone.

The other thing I've tried is just calling maven package on the async-http-client project after it is downloaded, but this isn't working either.

Some guidance on getting this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats your maven config used? Also since the projevt is built on top of netty, it needs certain netty dependencies on your machine as a prerequisite.

Comment: If you look at the dependency list in the pom.xml, you'll see that async-http-client has many Netty dependencies, about eight, and it's entirely possible that those dependencies have more transitive dependencies themselves. Personally, I wouldn't try to configure this manually unless I was confident, so I strongly recommend you use maven. I suggest you post a more detailed question about "The other thing I've tried is just calling maven package on the async-http-client project after it is downloaded, but this isn't working either."

Comment: Also, when you say "I would expect that everything would be inclusive if they are offering the lib stand alone" you are interpreting the readme excessively. All the readme says is "in order to add it to your Maven project, simply download from Maven central or add this dependency". It says "in order to add it to your _Maven project_". It doesn't say anything about standalone, all-inclusive JARs, and you can expect any JAR you download directly from Maven central to be Maven managed, which always means the possibility of transitive dependencies.

Comment: download `async-http-client` `pom.xml` and execute `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and it'll download all dependencies you need (got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084550/maven-command-line-to-download-the-dependencies-described-in-the-pom-xml)) but i strongly suggest you to set up a maven project instead

Comment: Thanks everbody. I made a maven proj skeleton, added the async-http-client dependancy to the pom file, used the mvn dependency:copy-dependencies (which I did not know I needed to do), then ran mvn package, then I open the project with Netbeans and it looks like its all going to finally work.